# Can't get movie player to play on my TV via HDMI connection

Tags: video, 12.10, display, hdmi

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Dell laptop.  laptop resolution is 1366x768.

I connected to my Phillips 42" TV using HDMI.  By changing channels I can get to HDMI4 and there my desktop wallpaper appears with an odd contrast, but the Movie Player with my movie never shows up.

Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you edit your question to include which video card is in your laptop?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have your desktop extended to your TV, meaning that Ubuntu is treating your two monitors as separate entities. You should be able to drag the movie player over to your TV (either by going past the right or left of your screen), and watch it that way. If you want both of your displays to show the same thing, simply open up Displays (it's a setting/program), and check the "Mirror Displays" option. I don't think you can mirror on displays that have different resolutions though.